# Jquery, Onclick, and Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have fiddled with this with absolutely no progress or luck. If I take out the .ajax it works fine but with the .ajax nothing fires, not even the random testing alerts. Can you see what I have done wrong with this? I have tried to follow the Jquery doc's. The PHP works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { // wait until the document is ready
$('div#chatroom').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'chatget.php',
    data: { chatroomid: = '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'},
    datatype: 'html',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#chatroom').append(response);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Fuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');
    }
}); // End Ajax  

alert('Fail');

}); // End onclick
});

</script>
```

Comment: Change `chatroomid: = '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'` to `chatroomid: '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'` So minus `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { // wait until the document is ready
$('div#chatroom').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'chatget.php',
    data: { chatroomid: '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'},
    datatype: 'html',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#chatroom').append(response);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Fuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');
    }
}); // End Ajax  

alert('Fail');

}); // End onclick
});

</script>
```

Can u try this code

Comment: It was the equal sign that was the problem XD;

Answer (score 2):

just loking at it ..  you have an extra `=` in data object

```
data: { chatroomid: = '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'},
              ------^^--- here
```

should be

```
 data: { chatroomid: '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'},
```

Answer (score 1):

Error seems here to me: an extra "="

```
chatroomid: = '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>'},
```

I usually test code with [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) when have errors like this one